# fwrite Across Domain?

Tags: php, fwrite

Is the following code below possible? Or no because its a security issue? I'd like to fwrite across from one folder to another so if the fwrite function is located at /1, can I fwrite to a .txt file on /2?

```
<?php
$myFile = "../news/derp.txt";
$fh = fopen('derp.txt', 'w') or die("File Can't Be Written To.");
$stringData = "Yo, .";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: You aren't writing across domains, you're writing to a different file on the same filesystem. If the web server user has write access to the file, it will work fine.

Comment: Just try it in the wonderful realm of `localhost`.

Comment: It is depend on the file permission has.

Comment: In localhost what would be the proper link? $myFile = "localhost/news/derp.txt";?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the script is being executed in a context where it has write permissions to the file, it should work.

The security issue question requires more information about what you are doing with it and whether or not the second directory is publicly visible.

Comment: So what would I specify the location as? If PHP looks at the folder its located in, could I specify the domain which would resolve to the localhost?

Comment: No, specifying a domain will cause it to use HTTP (which may or may not work, depending on your server's setup).

Comment: You have to specify the file system location of the area you are attempting to write to and it has to be mounted on the server as the first domain.

Comment: So if I wanted to go from /1 to /2 how would the url look? $myFile = "../2/derp.txt"; ?

Comment: Yes, '..' ascends in most systems.

Comment: Alright. Seems like I'm in for a rough time trying to figure out the correct url haha. Thanks a bunch man.

Answer (score 1):

A remote file would most likely not be writeable by PHP, but if it's a local folder, it just depends on whether PHP has write access to that folder + file.

Read this:

"If PHP has decided that filename specifies a local file, then it will try to open a stream on that file. The file must be accessible to PHP, so you need to ensure that the file access permissions allow this access. If you have enabled safe mode, or open_basedir further restrictions may apply."

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Answer (score 1):

PHP can write to anywhere on your filesystem. PHP is not limited to the domain of the server running it, which is why LFIs are so efficient.

Answer (score 1):

PHP can write to any directory it has write access to. If you don't have access to it, like if it's someone else's account on a shared server, then no you probably won't be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is yes. I was just unaware of the circumstances, and the correct way to ascend to the file. Here is the final working script.
Writing from /1/fwrite.php, here's the script.

```
<?php
$file = fopen("../2/derp.txt","w");
fwrite($file,"Hello World!");
fclose($file);
?>
```